# problem having with core java programming

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to write test case in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744146/how-to-write-test-case-in-java)

hi
I am facing the problem with writing test case for following method:

```
public class ABC{
public void updateUser(String emailId, HashMap hm) {
        String updateKey = createUniqueUserKey(emailId);
        int noOfColumn = (UserColumnFamily.getColumnNames()).size();
```

Comment: You really, really want to format your code. You can use the "Code Sample" icon in the editing box.

Comment: You already have an (almost) identical question.

Comment: Please stop repeatedly asking the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than specifics, you should probably stick to some common rules to make your method more "testable":

- Try to get rid of repeated code: for example, `UserColumnFamily.getColumnNames()` is repeated a couple of times;
- Break down your method into smaller methods; your methods tries to achieve too much so test cases will become extremely convoluted.  It is much easier to test methods that do one thing only.
- Try to "inject" the objects you need rather than creating them inside your method, or retrieving from static calls.  As you have lots of dependencies, you will need to set them up in your test case, which can become quite tricky.

Once your code is a bit cleaner, what your test cases assert will become much clearer.

Comment: Thank you Sébastien Le Callonne...